# conda list doesnt show channel name

Tags: conda

The conda list is not displaying the channel from which a package was installed it is blank. How to figure out from which channel the installed package came.

```
# conda list pyhive
# packages in environment at /data/opt/anaconda3:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyhive                    0.6.1            py39h06a4308_0
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions. For the `anaconda` tag: `Do not use this tag for questions about Conda environment management (instead use [conda]).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `defaults` Channel Packages

That is how packages installed from `defaults` meta-channel appear. It is effectively the same as an explicit `anaconda` or `main` channel.

### Options

There are a few options to get more information.

I will use the following example environment to showcase the behavior.

**Example Environment**

```bash
$ conda create -n foo -c defaults yaml
# ...
$ conda list -n foo
# packages in environment at /Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0
```

#### `show_channel_urls`

The Conda config setting `show_channel_urls` affects how channels are displayed, and in the context of `conda list` controls whether `defaults` will be explicitly be shown or not.

This can be set temporarily, with the `--show-channel-urls` argument:

```bash
$ conda list -n foo --show-channel-urls
# packages in environment at /Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0    defaults
```

Alternatively, this can be persistently enabled by setting the configuration variable:

```bash
$ conda config --set show_channel_urls true
## now it shows the channel by default
$ conda list -n foo
# packages in environment at /Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0    defaults
```

#### Other arguments

There are two other useful arguments to obtain more specific information on the package origin, namely,

**`--canonical`**

```bash
conda list -n foo --canonical
defaults/osx-64::yaml-0.2.5-haf1e3a3_0
```

which shows both the meta-channel "`defaults`" and the subdir "`osx-64`".

**`--explicit`**

```bash
conda list -n foo --explicit 
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: osx-64
@EXPLICIT
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/yaml-0.2.5-haf1e3a3_0.conda
```

This is the most informative format, since it actually specifies the full URL, which includes the real channel of origin, "`main`" - one of the channels within the `defaults` metachannel.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful option: "conda list  --show-channel-urls pyhive"  
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyhive                    0.6.1            py39h06a4308_0    defaults